# How to place a DOM element on the top right

Tags: css, css-float

This piece of code works, but I would like to know if it is the best way to place a dom element on the top right of a container.

the prerequisites are the following:
1) the DOM cannot be changed.
2) the CSS code with comment with *original code* cannot be changed.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jBme9/1/

---

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="prize-item">
            <div class="control-group ">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="form-prize-item-name" value="prize2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="">
            Edit
        </button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
.controls button{
    float: right;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
}

/* original code */
.control-group {
    background-color: #D9EDF7;
    padding: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/* original code */
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do what you have done, but if you want to place that somewhere in the middle of your web page you need to have an outer `div` with `position: relative;`

First of all things you wont need :

1) `float: right; /* In .controls button */`

2) You have a class called .`btn` so you don't need **.controls button** simply use `.btn` else your styles will apply to all buttons in `.controls`

3) button **doesn't** require `type=button` attribute...(Unless you are not using it to reset/submit anything than you need to specify)

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBme9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine. But you don't need `float:right` line. `position:absolute` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Your absolutely positioned element (the button) needs context for its absolute positioning, this can be done by declaring a parent element of it with position: relative. If you do not do this, the button will be positioned absolutely relative to the outer most parent element, ie the html tag.

Also your CSS has a redundant property, the float. No float is needed when absolutely positioning.

This is all you need:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make element class like

```
input[type="button"]
{
float:right;
}
input[type="text"]
{
float:right;
}
or

input[type="text"], input[type="button"]
{
float:right;
}
```